# Extract multiple matching words with variable value from a line

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to extract 2 words (vers,sec) from a line with variable value '3.0 & ntlmssp',

**vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp**

```
~$ echo $cifs
//192.168.10.11/cifs_share on /cifs_share type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp,cache=strict,username=testuser,domain=LAB,uid=30100,forceuid,gid=2050,forcegid,addr=192.168.10.11,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

I am looking for an output like this,

```
cifs_version : 3.0, Security : ntlmssp
```

I am able to extract one word vers, but how to extract 2 words (vers,sec)  and rename ?

```
~$ echo $cifs|grep -o 'vers=[^ ,]\+'
vers=3.0
```

How can I extract this, please help,

Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With plain `bash`:

```
~$ cifs='//192.168.10.11/cifs_share on /cifs_share type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp,cache=strict,username=testuser,domain=LAB,uid=30100,forceuid,gid=2050,forcegid,addr=192.168.10.11,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)'
~$ set -f; IFS='(,)=' arr=( $cifs ); set +f; v=""; s=""
~$ for((i=0;i<${#arr[@]};i++)); do
  [[ ${arr[i]} == "vers" ]] && v="${arr[i+1]}"
  [[ ${arr[i]} == "sec" ]] && s="${arr[i+1]}"
done
~$ printf 'cifs_version : %s, Security : %s\n' "$v" "$s"
cifs_version : 3.0, Security : ntlmssp
```

`set -f; IFS='(,)=' arr=( $cifs ); set +f` disables pathname expansion (`set -f`), assigns the input string to bash array `arr` with Input Filed Separator (variable `IFS`) set to parentheses, commas and equal signs, and re-enables pathname expansion (`set +f`). The elements of the `arr` array are now the different parts of the input string.

The loop simply loops on all elements of the array. When finding element `vers` we assign the next element to `v`, and when finding `sec` we assign the next element to variable `s`.

`printf` prints your desired output string.

With any `awk`:

```
~$ awk -F'[(,)=]' '{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if($i == "vers") v=$(i+1)
    if($i == "sec") s=$(i+1)
  }
} END {
  printf("cifs_version : %s, Security : %s\n", v, s)
}' <<< "$cifs"
cifs_version : 3.0, Security : ntlmssp
```

It is exactly the same as the plain `bash` solution, but in the form of a `awk` script. In `awk` the input field separator can be specified as a regular expression with the `-F` option. In this case we specify that the fields are separated by parentheses, commas or equal signs. The different fields are `$1 ... $NF` (the `NF` `awk` special variable is the number of fields).

Comment: awk - can you please explain if possible in this example,
thanks

Comment: I added some explanation for both solutions and slightly improved the first.

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*,vers=\([^,]*\),sec=\([^,]*\).*/cifs_version : \1, Security : \2/' file
cifs_version : 3.0, Security : ntlmssp
```

The above assumes `vers` and `sec` appear consecutively mid-line as shown in your sample input.

Answer (score 0):

@vijayedm : from here on it should be trivial

> ```
> mawk 'NF*=!_<NF' RS='[,() ]+' FS== OFS=' : '
> ```

```
vers : 3.0
sec : ntlmssp
cache : strict
username : testuser
domain : LAB
uid : 30100
gid : 2050
addr : 192.168.10.11
file_mode : 0755
dir_mode : 0755
rsize : 4194304
wsize : 4194304
bsize : 1048576
echo_interval : 60
actimeo : 1
```

> ```
> gawk 'NF *= NR < NF*NF' FS== OFS=' : ' RS='^[^(]+[^=]+,|[,() ]+'
> ```

```
vers : 3.0
sec : ntlmssp
```

or if you want them lined up without doing extra work :

> ```
> OFS='\r\t\t: '
> ```

```
vers            : 3.0
sec             : ntlmssp
cache           : strict
username        : testuser
domain          : LAB
uid             : 30100
gid             : 2050
addr            : 192.168.10.11
file_mode       : 0755
dir_mode        : 0755
rsize           : 4194304
wsize           : 4194304
bsize           : 1048576
echo_interval   : 60
actimeo         : 1
```

> ```
> OFS='\f\r\t'
> ```

```
vers
    3.0
sec
    ntlmssp
cache
    strict
username
    testuser
domain
    LAB
uid
    30100
gid
    2050
addr
    192.168.10.11
file_mode
    0755
dir_mode
    0755
rsize
    4194304
wsize
    4194304
bsize
    1048576
echo_interval
    60
actimeo
    1
```